# How to prove that momentum eigenstates are also eigenstates of asymmetric Landau Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, operators, commutator

$$H(B,E)=\frac{1}{2m}p_x^2+\frac{1}{2m}\left(p_y-\frac{q}{c}Bx\right)^2-qEx$$
This Hamiltonian commutes with $p_y$, therefore, $\langle y|k_y\rangle=e^{ik_yy}$ are eigenstates of $H$, but how can I prove it?
If I try the regular approach I'll will be left with an operator as an eigenvalue:
$$He^{ik_yy}=\left(\frac{1}{2m}p_x^2+\frac{1}{2m}\left(\hbar k_y-\frac{q}{c}Bx\right)^2-qEx\right)e^{ik_yy}$$
Is this sufficient to prove that it is indeed an eigenstate?
Thanks!

Comment: What you showed is that $\psi(x) e^{iyk_y}$ is an eigenfunction of $p_y$ for any $\psi(x)$. You must now find the  $\psi(x)$s that are eigenfunctions of the operator you deduced. One is not such an eigenfunction.

Answer (score 2):

Your real eigenstate is not $|k_y\rangle$ since the $y$ part does not cover all degrees of freedom. It's more like a "separation of variables" method where the $y$ part is easy to solve (momentum eigenstates).

Consider the leftover part of the Hamiltonian $H_{k_y}=\left(\frac{1}{2 m} p_{x}^{2}+\frac{1}{2 m}\left(\hbar k_{y}-\frac{q}{c} B x\right)^{2}-q E x\right)$ where the operators are $x, p_x$ and $k_y$. This is a reduced 1D Hamiltonian where you can obtain a set of solutions $|\psi_{n,k_y}\rangle$.

The logic is as follows: you actually block diagonalize $H$ in different $k_y$ sections; within each section, the Hamiltonian is $H_{k_y}$ which you can further diagonalize like any 1D problems.